# How function execution sequence works in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment that sends a Get request to server multiple times but with different arguments expecting different results.

This function accepts arguments and sends request successfully but there is a problem:

First execution of this function returns `null` but second execution returns first execution's result! and the problem is in execution sequence:
I added some toast comments to clarify: "Toast A" is in get request function and "Toast B" is after the function call. I figured out that "Toast A" is being executed **AFTER** "Toast B".

As you know by now, I am new to Java and answering this question helps me understand it better. My real question is not about sending Get request. I just want to know How java handles function's execution sequence. Thanks for guiding me.

This is how I call request function:

```
Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
header.put("user_id", "123");
String[] responseString = get_request(header);
//Toast B
```

Here is my request function:

```
public String[] get_request(final Map<String, String> header) {
    final String[] responseString = new String[1];

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getString(R.string.server) + "query.php", new Response.Listener<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            responseString[0] = response;
            //Toast A
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            responseString[0] = "";
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return header;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).add(stringRequest);
    return responseString;
}
```

Comment: The structure of Java isn't a whole lot different from any other language inspired by C syntax. Your code is pretty hard to read, though. If you want it to be easier to read, don't write all of your code in a single method. In addition, as the answer mentions, there are _tons_ of existing libraries to facilitate HTTP requests. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @MehdiMaazi, `Toast` B to be shown before `Toast` A is normal behaviour here because your `getRequest()` method uses Volley's **asynchronous request** method which is expected to return in some later point of time after successfully getting the `response` from the remote server(Toast A will be shown then on successful response) meanwhile your normal execution will continue ie. Toast B will be immediately shown.

Comment: Great! Thanks @cgb_pandey!